# Curly Braces in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Why does this Compile:

```
int main() 
{
    {}  
}
```

But this does not:

```
    {}

int main() 
{  
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First case, you're defining a block inside a function, which is allowed (it limits visibility).
Second case, you're defining an anonymous block, which is not allowed (it needs to be predeceded by a function definition, otherwise, the compiler will never know when it will have to execute it)

Answer (score 20):

`{}` is a do-nothing statement (specifically in the C grammar it is an empty *compound-statement*). You can put statements in functions. You can't put statements elsewhere.

I suppose the reason the standard doesn't forbid an empty statement in your first example is that although it's pointless, it does no harm, and introducing rules for when braces are allowed to be empty would complicate the grammar for no benefit.

And, to be pedantic, I suppose I should point out that neither does the grammar define any other construct at file scope, of which `{}` is a valid instance, and *that's* why the second one is invalid.

Comment: @Acme: Steve's answer was for C.  For C++, the answer is similar: Within a function definition, statements including `{}` are valid.  There is no other place a statement is allowed.  There are other uses of `{}` (namespace, class, struct, union, enum, initializer, linkage specification), but all of those require more tokens to be valid syntax, not just `{}` alone.

Comment: Empty compound-statements are probably allowed because of macros. Since macros can be expanded to nothing, the simple `{ DBG("Hello"); }` would fail to compile when `DBG` is expanded to nothing, which would be surprising.

Comment: @Matthieu: I was thinking about that, but the `assert` macro when it's disabled doesn't result in nothing, it results in `(void)0` or similar. And your DBG macro doesn't result in an empty compound statement `{}`, it results in `{;}`: a compound statement containing an empty statement. Certainly it is useful to have empty compound-statements from time to time, and macros are an example, but given how `assert` is defined I don't want to go out and say that the standards committee *expects* people to write macros that end up expanding to nothing, since they avoided that themselves.

Comment: So, since I couldn't think of an example where an empty compound-statement is definitively *required*, I'm sticking to "there's no point banning them" as my suggested rationale :-)

Comment: @Acme: what @achepler says: my answer does apply to C++ as well, there is nothing in the C++ grammar either to make `{}` valid on its own at file scope. A namespace definition starts with the keyword namespace and optionally a name, so `{}` is valid after that but not on its own. For that matter in C++ `struct foo {};` is valid, but that also doesn't mean `{}` on its own is. In both C and C++, `void foo() {}` is valid - again that doesn't permit just `{}` with no introduction.

Comment: @Steve: I should have included the `;` within the macro! The reason not to, is obviously not to mess up one-liners: `while(--i) DBG(x[i])` with an embedded `;` would really surprise everyone when `DBG` expands to nothing! On the other hand, expanding to `(void)0` the macro still expands to a proper statement (even if optimized out).

Answer (score 5):

Because code defined in a global scope is not allowed in **C**. Remember, in **C**, **every line of code but variable declaration/initialization** must lie within a function.

If you are **inside** a function you can have all `{}` blocks you want.

Comment: includes/defines are allowed outside functions too

Comment: @BlackBear: true, but they're not C statements. They're just macro preprocessors.

Answer (score 3):

Because the only things that may appear at the top level of a translation unit are declarations or function definitions; compound statements (empty or not) may not appear at that level.